# Missing references errors on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

I have a solution with a project that i developed using *Visual Studio 2013* and it was working as intended. I then formatted my computer to upgrade to *Windows 10* and decided to install *Visual Studio 2015* instead and now I'm getting a lot of missing reference errors when they are installed, does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Some of the errors:

[image: Errors]

A good example is that I have `Microsoft.Net.Http` package installed but it's not recognizing it where I have `using System.Web.Http;`

I installed *Visual Studio 2015* with the same user I'm using to run it (It's a personal computer and I'm the single user) and am running it as administrator.

If you need any extra information please leave a comment and I'll edit the question.

Comment: Look into Nuget Package Manager. Any missing packages?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it, no.

Comment: How are you referencing the dlls? Were they NuGet packages? If not, where you just pointing to a folder of external resources (DLLs) which no longer exists?

Comment: try to reload your PC

Comment: They are all NuGet packages.

Comment: I had this issue when updating to VS2015 - I updated the version of System.Web and the related dependencies (which look like what you are having issues with as well) to the 5.0.2 version fixed these. Best bet is to remove them all from within NuGet manager, then readd them making sure you have the updated version.

Comment: What I do is, Right Click on Solution Explorer > Enable Nuget Package Restore.

Comment: Try "update-package -Reinstall" in Nuget Package Console.

Comment: I did try this but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended by creating a new project and just copying the files and only a few lines of configurations I needed from the old project and that solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Update-Package in Package manager console
may sort it out if it is a missing / mismatched package issue

Comment: Perhaps its a permissions thing.
Did you install as the same user your using it as?

I'm not sure on Win 10 but can you "Run as Administrator" and see if that's any better.

Comment: Yes, I installed with the same user (It's a personal computer and I'm the single user) and am running as administrator.

Comment: Just trying to give options!
Geez - you guys somethimes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a few months ago. In my case the following two steps worked:

1) Delete the hidden `.vs` folder from the solution folder, it's next to the .sln file (but close visual studio first)

2) From the .csproj file, remove these entries (if they exist)

```
<RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>
```

And

```
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets'))" />
</Target>
```

Comment: I can't find `<RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>` anywhere in the project.

Comment: @VítorMartins - and what about the rest of the csproj's content? can you post it perhaps?